# In R shiny, how to use on the UI side a value computed on the SERVER side?

Tags: r, shiny

In my R shiny app, I would like to adjust the height of my `d3heatmap` (see package [d3heatmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/d3heatmap/index.html)) as a function of the number of rows of my data frame; there is an argument `height` in the `d3heatmapOutput` to specify that.

However, my data frame is computed on the server side, so how can I pass its number of rows from the server side to the ui side?

Here is the example reflecting what I would like to do:

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidRow(
    selectInput("am", "Automatic (0) or manual (1) transmission?", 
                choices = c(0,1)), 

    # How can I have the 'height' argument equal to 'output$height'? 
    # I cannot use 'textOutput("height")' since it gives html code, not a value.
    d3heatmapOutput("heatmap", height = "400px") 
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    mtcars2 = reactive({
      mtcars[which(mtcars$am == input$am),]
    })
    output$height <- renderText({
      paste0(15*nrow(mtcars2()), "px")
    })
    output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({ 
      d3heatmap(mtcars2(), scale = "column") 
    })
  }
))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uiOutput` in `ui.R` and `renderUI` in `server.R` to dynamically add the `d3heatmapOutput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(d3heatmap)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidRow(
    selectInput("am", "Automatic (0) or manual (1) transmission?", 
                choices = c(0,1)), 

    uiOutput("ui_heatmap")

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    mtcars2 = reactive({
      mtcars[which(mtcars$am == input$am),]
    })
    output$ui_heatmap <- renderUI({
      d3heatmapOutput("heatmap", height = paste0(15*nrow(mtcars2()), "px")) 
    })    
    output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({ 
      d3heatmap(mtcars2(), scale = "column") 
    })

  }
))
```

You can then set the height of the heatmap in the server side of the app.