# d3heatmap and rcharts don't work in different tabs in a Shiny application

Tags: shiny, rcharts

I've hit a bit of a problem making an application using the nvd3 library via rCharts and the d3heatmap library on different tabs of a Shiny application (or indeed, the same tab of a Shiny application).

I've made a little example here that shows the problem, basically the dendrogram is drawn but the heatmap isn't. If you get rid of the rCharts tab though it works fine. Some sort of conflict between the two libraries?

I can fix the first problem (d3.tip is not a function) with the commented line beginning # HTML, so it draws the coloured boxes, but you can't interact with them and the rownames aren't printed (error: Cannot read property "apply" of undefined).

```
library(d3heatmap)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  # HTML('<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>'),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("A heatmap demo")
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel( # set up tabbed output
        tabPanel("First panel", showOutput("barchart", lib =  "nvd3")),
        tabPanel("Second panel", d3heatmapOutput("heatmap"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({
    d3heatmap(
      mtcars, scale = "column",
      colors = "YlOrRd"
    )
  })

  output$barchart <- renderChart({

    hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart")
    n1$addParams(dom = 'barchart')

    return(n1)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is based on the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271208/in-r-shiny-how-to-use-on-the-ui-side-a-value-computed-on-the-server-side). I think it something to do with evaluation of the JavaScript which comes before other evaluations.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(d3heatmap)
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # HTML('<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>'),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("A heatmap demo")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel( # set up tabbed output
        tabPanel("First panel", showOutput("barchart", lib =  "nvd3")),
        tabPanel("Second panel",  uiOutput("ui_heatmap"))
      )
    )
  )
)
d3heatmap(mtcars, scale="column", colors="YlOrR")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mtcars2 = reactive({
    mtcars
  })

  output$ui_heatmap <- renderUI({
    d3heatmapOutput("heatmap", height = paste0(15*nrow(mtcars2()), "px")) 
  })    
  output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({ 
    d3heatmap(mtcars2(), scale = "column") 
  })

  output$barchart <- renderChart({

    hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart")
    n1$addParams(dom = 'barchart')
    return(n1)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, setting up a reactive UI was all it took. For future visitors, here is the complete code that works

```
library(d3heatmap)
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("A heatmap demo")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel( # set up tabbed output
        tabPanel("First panel", showOutput("barchart", lib =  "nvd3")),
        tabPanel("Second panel", uiOutput("ui_heatmap"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$ui_heatmap <- renderUI({
    d3heatmapOutput("heatmap")
  })

  output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({ 
    d3heatmap(mtcars, scale = "column") 
  })

  output$barchart <- renderChart({

    hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, type = "multiBarChart")
    n1$addParams(dom = 'barchart')

    return(n1)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```